# How to resolve this error stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, selenium-chromedriver

Please find attached code:

```
 IWebElement webElement = this.wait.Until<IWebElement>(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("search-for-deals-results")));
    if (webElement != null)
    {
      ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elements = webElement.FindElements(By.XPath("tbody//tr//a[contains(@href,'public/dealList')]"));
      this.issuerList = new List<FileData>();
     
      foreach (var data in elements.Select(l => new
      {
        link = l.GetAttribute("href"),
        name = l.Text
      }))
        this.issuerList.Add(new FileData()
        {
          Name = data.name, 
          Url = data.link 

        });
      this.dealsList = new List<FileData>();
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(issueName))
        this.issuerList = this.issuerList.Where<FileData>((Func<FileData, bool>) (s => s.Name.Contains(issueName))).ToList<FileData>();
      Console.WriteLine("Download Process Started: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
      this.ProcessIssures(this.issuerList, false);
      Console.WriteLine("fdfs" + this.dealsList.Count.ToString());
      this.ProcessIssures(this.dealsList, true);
    }
  }
  Download.driver.Quit();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i am getting the error in for each loop where i am adding name and url to the issuerlist

Comment: would you please share, what is the issue?